# iOS App gets invalid user location

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, location, core-location

when I'm trying to show the user location on my map it shows the location is somewhere in the ocean (lat = 0.000 , lon = 0.000) , I have set the simulated location to be in london and still nothing.

when i try to compile the app on my iphone its doesn't ask for permission to get user current location , just when i enable the app for using location services in the iphone settings , the app shows the user current location.

any idea why it does it?
this is my viewDidLoad :

```
_locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
_locationManager.delegate = self;
_locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
    [_locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    [_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}
_locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
_locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Comment: Is you iPhone running iOS 7 or 8?

Comment: Add `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` key to your info.Plist file

Comment: I'm running 7 on my iphone and 8 on the simulator , i have already added the description, any other ideas?

Comment: Perhaps _locationManager is being deallocated? How is it defined?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to adding both they both do different things

```
[_locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
[_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
```

**requestWhenInUseAuthorization**

use `[_locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];` when you want to get location updates when app is Active of foreground mode and not when in background .

**requestAlwaysAuthorization**

use `[_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];` when you want to get location updates Even when your app is in background mode. So OS would ask for permissions accordingly

**Adding Keys to info.Plist**

It is now mandetory to add either `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`  or `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` Key to your info.Plist depending upon which permission you are asking for .

The value to this key should be  a `NSString` explaining user why the app wants to use location services something like "We need your location for XYZ reason"

If iOS does not find above key in your Plist file , it will ignore location request. 
Hope this helps. By the way I reccomand you to watch WWDC 2014 video "Whats new in Core Location", all iOS8 changes have been nicely explained.

**Other Changes in Code**

Also one more thing i see in your code , You are creating new instance of `_locationManager` in 3rd line , Means you are creating new object after assigning delegate to locationManager, should not do that too.

Comment: well first thanks for the answer! but i have seen the changes that needed to be done when changing to ios 8 , but i didnt say that i have changed to ios 8 , the app is not showing user location on both ios 7 or 8 , and i did add the description. so still , any idea why it doesn't ask for location permission?

Comment: May be, you are creating new locationManager Object again after assigning delegate to it, So that might be causing the problem.

Comment: after deleting the new location manager it asks me (in the device) for location permission , but when i hit ok it does nothing and i need to go back to the settings. in the simulator its the same problem

Comment: Ok, Have you added `CLLocationManagerDelegate` to your .h file ?